# Unexpected infinite loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, cookies

I was doing a cookie practice in javascript and developed the following code:

```
function getCookie(kname) {
  var fullkeyname = kname + "=";
  var fullcookie = document.cookie;
  var acookies = fullcookie.split(";");
  for (var i = 0; i < acookies.length; i++) {
    var cookie = acookies[i];
    while (acookies[i].charAt(0) == " ") { //THE ISSUE IS HERE
      cookie = cookie.substring(1);
    }
    if(cookie.indexOf(fullkeyname) == 0) {
    return cookie.substring(fullkeyname.length, cookie.length);
  }
}
return "";
}
```

It didnt worked and seemed to rise and infinite loop so I tracked my code with "document.write" in various parts and discovered that if I change the "while" condition it will work as follows:

```
function getCookie(kname) {
  var fullkeyname = kname + "=";
  var fullcookie = document.cookie;
  var acookies = fullcookie.split(";");
  for (var i = 0; i < acookies.length; i++) {
    var cookie = acookies[i];
    while (cookie.charAt(0) == " ") { //RIGHT HERE
      cookie = cookie.substring(1);
    }
    if (acookies[i].indexOf(fullkeyname) == 0) {
      return cookie.substring(fullkeyname.length, cookie.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

Now my code works as expected, however I dont know why, since I have set the value of cookies to "cookie=acookies[i]" I dont understand why it should loop indefinetly if I dont use the "cookie" variable.
Question is: why does the code works with my "cookie" variable and not with the "acookies[i]" even though the sould have the same value at that given moment?

Comment: `ifcookie.indexOf(fullkeyname)==0)` - I see a missing `(` inthe first block of code. Is it a typo?

Comment: because you're not modifying `acookies[i]` in the body of your `while` loop. When you assigned `acookies[i]` to the variable `cookie`, you just set a pointer; so the assignment `cookie = cookie.substring(1);` doesn't change `acookies`, it merely updates the pointer

Comment: `you just set a pointer` - no, that's not right, as cookies[i] is a string, `cookie = cookies[i]` **copies** the value - there is no "pointer" or, more correctly, reference

Comment: just use `var cookie = acookies[i].trim();` and forget the while loop

Comment: Jaromanda, I guess I will haha, but I wanted to know why it was giving an error anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It causes an infinite loop because you are checking if the first character of **acookies** is an empty space, then if it is, you are removing the first character of **cookie** (NOT **acookies**). Therefore, if **acookies** does have a space as the first character, the while statement will always be true because you aren't removing that space from **acookies**

```js
function getCookie(kname) {
  var fullkeyname = kname + "=";
  var fullcookie = document.cookie;
  var acookies = fullcookie.split(";");
  for (var i = 0; i < acookies.length; i++) {

    while (acookies[i].charAt(0) == " ") { //THE ISSUE IS HERE
      acookies[i] = acookies[i].substring(1); // FIXED THIS LINE
    }

    var cookie = acookies[i];

    if(cookie.indexOf(fullkeyname) == 0) {
    return cookie.substring(fullkeyname.length, cookie.length);
  }
}
return "";
}
```

edited for typo, thank you FREE_AND_OPEN_SOURCE

Comment: You mean `acookies[i] = acookies[i].substring(1);`

Comment: You are missing `(` before `if` statement. Also, you need to set `cookie = acookies[i]` after `while` loop.

Comment: @LuisE. You are still missing `cookie = acookies[i]` after `while` loop. Your code will not give the result as OP wants.

Comment: @FREE_AND_OPEN_SOURCE good catch, was just copy pasting, thanks.

Comment: Oh I noticed that it wouldnt work I just eanted to know WHY it didn't in first place

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem in while loop

```
while (acookies[i].charAt(0) == " ") { //THE ISSUE IS HERE
      cookie = cookie.substring(1);
}
```

once acookies[i].charAt(0) == " " becomes true, it will keep on looping and will never get to go outside while loop to increment the value of 'i'.

and in the second version of the code you're modifying the cookie variable itself which make the while condition false which moves the control out of the loop and continue execution.